# When i press the button, nothing happens

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to get to use the `<form>` to integrate with PHP, however when i press the button, nothing happens. I am using the same  tags and arguments as i am using on another .php file which works fine, also if i on the same php file add  standalone with the button, without the content, it works. So i suspect some of the content is bugging this. Anyone knows a solution?

Here is my code that is relevant:

```
            <form class="form-wizard" method="post">                    
            <div class="steps-progress">
                <div class="progress-indicator"></div>
            </div>
            
            <ul>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#tab2-1" data-toggle="tab"><span>1</span>Kontakt informasjon</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#tab2-2" data-toggle="tab"><span>2</span>Innehaver</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#tab2-3" data-toggle="tab"><span>3</span>Egenerklæring</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#tab2-4" data-toggle="tab"><span>4</span>Betaling</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab2-1">
                    
                    <div class="row">
                        
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="tw_fullname">Fullnavn</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tw_fullname" id="tw_fullname" data-validate="required" value="<?php echo $db_firstname." ".$db_lastname;?>" placeholder="Skriv inn fullnavn til kontakt person" disabled/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="tw_email">E-post adresse</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="tw_email" id="tw_email" data-validate="required" value="<?php echo $db_email;?>" placeholder="Skriv inn e-post adresse til kontakt person" disabled/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="row">
                        
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="tw_postaladdress">Postadresse</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tw_postaladdress" id="tw_postaladdress" data-validate="required" value="<?php echo $db_address1;?>" placeholder="Skriv inn adressen til kontakt person" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="tw_postalzip">Postkode</label>
                                <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]" class="form-control" name="tw_postalzip" id="tw_postalzip" data-validate="required" value="<?php echo $db_postal_code;?>" placeholder="Skriv inn postkoden til kontakt person" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
        
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                
                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2-2">
                    
                    <div class="row">
                        
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="tw_innehaverfullname">Innehavers Fullnavn</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tw_innehaverfullname" id="tw_innehaverfullname" data-validate="required" value="<?php echo $db_firstname." ".$db_lastname;;?>" placeholder="Skriv inn fullnavnet til innehaver" disabled/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="tw_innehaveremail">Innehavers E-post Adresse</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="tw_innehaveremail" id="tw_innehaveremail" data-validate="required" value="<?php echo $db_email;?>" placeholder="Skriv inn e-post adressen til innehaver" disabled/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="tw_innehaverphone">Innehavers Telefon Nummer</label>
                                <input type="phone" class="form-control" name="tw_innehaverphone" id="tw_innehaverphone" data-validate="required" value="<?php echo $db_phone_no;?>" placeholder="Skriv inn telefon nummer til innehaver" disabled/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="tw_innehaverpid">PID-Nummer</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tw_innehaverpid" id="tw_innehaverpid" value="<?php echo $db_norid_pid;?>" placeholder="Skriv inn PID-Nummer dersom det gjelder privatperson" disabled/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="tw_innehaverorgnr">Org.nr</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tw_innehaverorgnr" id="tw_innehaverorgnr" value="<?php echo $db_business_number;?>" placeholder="Skriv inn organisasjonsnummer dersom det gjelder bedrift" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                    
                </div>

                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2-3">
                    
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            
                            <input type="file" class="form-control file2 inline btn btn-primary" name="tw_noriddeclaration" id="tw_noriddeclaration" data-label="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-file'></i> Last opp egenerklæring" />
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    
                </div>
                
                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2-4">
                    <h3><strong>Bestillingsoversikt</strong></h3>
                    <p>Dette er en oversikt over hva du er i ferd med å bestille hos oss. Vennligst gå gjennom hele ordren for feil før du trykker bestill. Når bestilling er sendt inn er den bindende.</p>
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped datatable" id="table-2">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Tjeneste</th>
                                <th>Beskrivelse</th>
                                <th>Pris</th>
                                <th>Varighet</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Domenenavn</td>
                            <td><?php echo $domainName;?></td>
                            <td>Kr 4,99 NOK /første året</td>
                            <td>1 år</td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table><br>

                    <h3><strong>Betalingsmetode</strong></h3>
                    <p>Velg betalingsmetoden du ønsker å benytte for å gjennomføre bestillingen.</p>
                        
                    <div class="radio radio-replace">
                        <input type="radio" id="rd-1" name="radio1" checked>
                        <label><strong>Faktura (kreditt)</strong> - Fungerer kun dersom du ble innvilget kreditt hos oss, kredittvurdering kan bli gjennomført.</label>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="radio radio-replace">
                        <input type="radio" id="rd-2" name="radio1">
                        <label><strong>Faktura (forhåndsbetalt)</strong> - Tjenesten aktiveres når fakturaen er betalt.</label>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="radio radio-replace">
                        <input type="radio" id="rd-3" name="radio1" disabled>
                        <label><strong>VISA</strong></label>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="radio radio-replace">
                        <input type="radio" id="rd-4" name="radio1" disabled>
                        <label><strong>Mastercard</strong></label>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="checkout_complete">Utfør bestilling</button>
                    

                    <!--<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info"value="Utfør bestilling" name="checkout_complete">-->
                    <!--<form method="POST">-->
                    <!--</form>-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <!-- end Checkout form-->
```

and the very simple PHP side of the code which does nothing except confirming if the form works, which it doesn't because nothing happens when i press the submit button:

```
if(isset($_POST['checkout_complete'])) {
    die("DEBUG: ".$_POST["tw_email"]);
  }
}
```

Also, it's not the  tag that's the issue, because as you can see in the code, i also tried which didn't work:

```
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info"value="Utfør bestilling" name="checkout_complete">
```

If anyone have any ideas to why this doesn't work, and how i can get arround this, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 1):

You have some disabled fields, but disabled fields are not sent on submit.
You can try using *readonly* instead of *disabled*

And make shure that the variables you use to prefill the *value* attributes are initialized:

```php
<!-- using the shorthand 'echo' -->
<input type="email" value="<?= $db_email ?? '---' ?>
```

Also, the piece of your code:

```php
if(isset($_POST['checkout_complete'])) {
    die("DEBUG: ".$_POST["tw_email"]);
  }
}
```

has one too many closing braces (but maybe it's a typo)

Answer (score 0):

Your code as presented fails because you have not included a value attribute for the submit button. Consequently `if(isset($_POST['checkout_complete'])` will not evaluate to `true`.

Adding a value attribute will solve this issue.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="checkout_complete" value="someValue">Utfør bestilling</button>
```